# Not able to import "time.h" in contiki

Tags: c, contiki

I am trying to create a simple program in which I have imported "time.h", but I am getting `fatal error: time.h: No such file or directory` error on compiling the code.
Following is the code I am trying to compile for "Zolertia z1" module

```
#include <time.h>
#include "contiki.h"
#include <stdio.h>

PROCESS(hello_world_process, "Hello world process");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&hello_world_process);
PROCESS_THREAD(hello_world_process, ev, data)
{
  PROCESS_BEGIN();

printf("Clock Second is: %u",(unsigned int)CLOCK_SECOND);

  PROCESS_END();
}
```

**NOTE:** This error message is displayed when I am trying to compile it for the z1 module. I can compile the same code for "native" target and "srf06-cc26xx" module (TI cc2650)

Comment: Contiki has its own stuff, you can't use the standard c library. I'm not even 100% sure that printf exists there, but I could be wrong, I was using a different OS for those devices.

Answer (score 2):

time.h might well be not implemented for contiki, since it is a minimal OS. There is however in its documentation a function called [clock_seconds](http://contiki.sourceforge.net/docs/2.6/a01664.html#ga8bbd5d5a773349139eee79d365af36ab) in clock.h that should do what you want.